# ADC for the raspberry pi zero w

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, analog-to-digital, pitft

Does anyone know of an ADC that I can use for a joystick to connect to the raspberry pi zero w? I have the adafruit pitft plus 2.8 resistive touch screen installed and it uses all the SPI pins I think.

Comment: Hi again... there are a couple of standard ones: MCP3008 & ADS1115 (with some variation). They both (I think) come on a small PCB & connect to the i2c GPIO pins (3 & 5). For your application I don't think there is any relevant difference, so just get the cheapest one you can find depending on where you are. Also, the i2c pins can be shared.

Comment: The mcp3008 connects via SPI from what reasearch I've done says. That's the one I inteded to get because it has 8 channels but I don't have pins open for it to use.

Comment: Ok, I need to check that. Then it is ADS1115 I have (or 1118?), and that one uses I2C.

Comment: If you need more channels you can get more chips. They can share the bus.

Comment: Oh, awesome! How many things do you think I can have connected to the bus (i2c bus?) I believe the LCD touchscreen connects to it as well.

Comment: And I was hoping for 5 channels but if 4 is all there is on one chip then I make have to make due with that. I'm messing with tight space inside a gamboy advance.

Comment: It says [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008) "You can use either the hardware SPI bus, or any four GPIO pins and software SPI to talk to the MCP3008."

Comment: What confused me about that was "any four gpio pins", any? Nothing special about them just basic gpio pins?

Comment: I think there is some theoretical limit, like 256, and then it depends on how much data you are sending, i.e. the sample rate. A joystick does not need high sample rate.

Comment: Alrighty. I'll look into it. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: Any four pins: I think it means "any except X, Y, Z..." but I do not know exactly.

Comment: Ohhhh okay. I'll do more research

Comment: In theory you can use 'normal' gpio pins for any communication (SPI,I2C, UART). But in practice this can be very error prone when your not using a real time OS.  The arduino is very successful in doing software serial but you have full control over the processor. on the Pi, the OS is doing many other things, so expecting your code to handle 'bit-banging' out the serial data on a GPIO pin is not going to be very reliable

Comment: So then how would I go about adding a joystick? Are you saying that I could add one but there would be noticeable input lag?